# How to transfer specific data from one excel sheet to another in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically, I have two excel sheets. What I am trying to do is to copy specific cell value from current cell to another. Let say, I have a form sheet of cash deposits:

Cash deposits form info:
[image]

and then, I need to copy and paste some of the data needed to another form.

This is the form where I want to paste the cell value from cash deposits:

[image]

I tried Macro but I have a limited knowledge about it and it seems difficult for me. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub move_data()

Dim main_sheet As String
Dim target_sheet As String

Dim info1 As String
Dim target_info1 As String

Dim info2 As String
Dim target_info2 As String

'CONFIG
'--------------------------
main_sheet = "Sheet1" 'set sheet name to copy from
target_sheet = "Sheet2" 'set sheet name to paste in

'cells to copy
info1 = "A1"
info2 = "B1"

'cells to paste
target_info1 = "B1"
target_info2 = "B2"
'----------------------

Sheets(target_sheet).Range(target_info1) = _
Sheets(main_sheet).Range(info1)

Sheets(target_sheet).Range(target_info2) = _
Sheets(main_sheet).Range(info2)

End Sub
```

If you need to copy/paste more cells, just add more `String` variables as `info1` and `info2` with their correspoding target cell to paste in and add the following code before the `End Sub` making the corresponding changes in the variable names.

```
Sheets(target_sheet).Range(target_info2) = _
Sheets(main_sheet).Range(info2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to copy *the values* of one set of cells into another is as follows:

Say you want to copy the range "A2:G101" (100×7 table) from Sheet1 to "F2:L101" (100×7 table) of Sheet2

```
Sheet2.Range("F2").Resize(100,7).Value = Sheet1.Range("A2").Resize(100,7).Value
```

<sub>In other posts you will see the `.Value` omitted because it is the default property, but it is not recommended to do so because it hides the intent of the code.</sub>

The above works with [named ranges] in the `Range()` specification as well as "A1" style referencing. The `.Resize()` command expands the reference from one cell to multiple rows and columns (given as `rows`, `columns`).